# How to see the most recent bids on different marketplaces for ERC721 token?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, nft, etherscan, erc721

I had a similar question regarding different listings. Since there can be multiple listings for the same ERC721 token, it was only possible to retrieve the data about those listings using APIs of different marketplaces.

Is there an API to retrieve the most recent (or highest) bid from multiple marketplaces? If not, can I access that information on Etherscan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, it depends on how the bid is placed. As an example:

1. It is possible for you to create a script, which will fetch data from multiple smart contracts that represent those marketplaces and calculate which one is the highest price for that ERC721 token, if the marketplace is a decentralized defi marketplace that is using smart contracts.
2. But if it's an web2 marketplace like coinbase etc. Then I am afraid we don't have much choice there since the information like who's making the bids and of what amount is being stored in the servers that they are maintaining and API's are only way to access them.